# has_one relation controller update rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, controller, has-one

I have 2 models. Task and Location

Each task has_one location

task.rb

```
has_one :location
```

I am trying to create my controller for the Location model. 
This is the new form

```
    <%= form_for(@task.build_Location, :url => task_Location_path(@task)) do |f| %>
        Fields
      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

and the edit form

```
    <%= form_for(@task.Location, :url => task_Location_path(@task)) do |f| %>
        Fields
      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

currently all functions operate properly with the exception of Update.

```
def create
  @location = @task.create_Location(params[:location])
end
def update
  @location = @task.locations.find(params[:id])
end
```

What is the proper way to define this method?

Comment: `@location.update_attributes(params[:location])` could work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def update
  @location = @task.location.update_attributes(params[:location])
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do but...

you usually want to access @task via it's id; also, if a has_one, it wouldn't be pluralized.

If you were trying to update a task's name to 'something' you could do something like:

```
def update
  @location=Location.find(params[:id])
  @location.task.name="something"
  @location.save
end
```

Comment: I just want the update method to properly update the attributes that are specified in the forms.

Comment: you'll want something like capcode's; also look at attr_accessible - will need something like tasks_attributes

Comment: I appreciate your help, You got me pointed in the right direction. That solution above is what finally worked for me. Thanks